# Why no use of locative preposition?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence `俺の机には置くな`, the preposition that expresses 'on' (上) doesn't appear.

Is it common in Japanese?

In English (*put **on** the table*), French (*mets **sur** la table*), and Mandarin (放在桌子**上**), this semantic item should appear, so it sounds to me a bit counterintuitive.

Answer (score 3):

上 does not directly mean "on".  It means ["above", "upper", "***on*** top", etc](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8A).  Omitting it in the Japanese is the same as omitting "top" in English.

> - 俺の机[に]{L}は置くな　→　Don't put it ***on*** my desk
> - 俺の机[の上に]{LLL}は置くな　→　Don't put it ***on top of*** my desk

If something is ***on*** the desk, you know it must be on ***top*** of it (unless you're talking about another universe with different gravity; some kind of magnetic desk; etc.  In those cases, you might have to specify which side/face "on" refers to).

Comment: Here に neither mean 'on', right? As we can have 明日おおさかに行きます。It roughly indicates direction or location, and the rest is inferred from the context?

Comment: Part of constraint implicitly comes from 置く too — if it was eg 付ける, かける, etc then it’d lose the need to be on the top of the desk and become more ambiguous... 置く seems to necessitate a flat, sufficiently-large “top”.

Comment: @starckman:  Yes, here に essentially means "on".  [The particle に has many meanings](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AB), sometimes implicit.